# PHP: How to parse a MySQL "LEFT JOIN"?

Tags: php, c++, mysql, join, left-join

I have been trying to determine how to parse the return value of a query that has a "LEFT JOIN" statement in it.

I don't know if this information matters or not, but I have an application that is written in C++ and a MySQL database that the application accesses through PHP.

I am retrieving related data from two tables with one query by using a MySQL "LEFT JOIN" statement.

The problem that I am encountering is how to determine whether or not a given row from the "left" table has a match from the "right" table.

Here is an example situation:

I have two tables that are called "leftTable" and "rightTable", both of which
have three columns.

- leftTable:
  column1 - column2 - column3
- rightTable:
  column1 - column2 - column3

Here is some example code, I know that this may be unfamiliar to those who don't know C++ very well, but here it is all the same:

```
// For those who are not very familiar with PHP, the "mysql_fetch_row"
// function returns the next unreturned row from the passed-in "query 
// results" argument

// Loop through all of the rows that were returned from the query:
while (resultsRow = mysql_fetch_row(queryResults))
{
    // Store the values of the "left" table's fields:
    leftColumn1 = resultsRow [0];
    leftColumn2 = resultsRow [1];
    leftColumn3 = resultsRow [2];


    // Store the values of the "right" table's fields:
    rightColumn1 = resultsRow [3];
    rightColumn2 = resultsRow [4];
    rightColumn3 = resultsRow [5];
}

// Obviously this code will NOT run as-is in C++; it is just a simplified 
// example.
```

The problem that I am encountering is that if a row from the "left" table does not have a matching row from the "right" then trying to retrieve the fields from the right table will cause the application to crash, because the "resultsRow" only contains three fields (the three from the "left" table); therefore, trying to access any index beyond index[2] causes a memory access violation.

I hope that my question is not too localized, although I don't think it is, because even though my example may have been written in C++, the concept of what I am asking must be solved in any situation.

I can think of other ways of how accomplish what I am seeking, but I think that a "JOIN" is probably the most readable and strait forward approach.

I have tried using Google to find an answer for my question, but all I can find are questions about how to return data from multiple tables, not on how to parse the data itself. 
Maybe this is because I don't know how to word my question correctly, or maybe it is because my question is too localized; I don't know.

P.s. I know C++ quite well (in my opinion anyway) but not SQL or PHP.  I picked  up (more like scrounged up, really) both of these languages, because an open-source project that I got involved with a few months ago, has them in it, so please don't be too harsh on me if I am asking a stupid question.
Also, if you give an answer, please be informative and descriptive, because of the aforementioned reason: I have little knowledge of SQL and PHP.

Thank-you.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want an inner join?

Comment: Well seeing as I am inexperienced with SQL that may be what I am looking for.  What I am trying to do is have a one-to-many relationship. The left table contains the base data, and the right table may or may not contain additional data.

Comment: An inner join will only return results if there is a match in both the left and right tables whereas a left join will return everything from the left table and only rows that match your join condition from the right table. What is the SQL query you are using right now?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, work and such have been pretty crazy as of late.  Here is an actual situation with which I am working: The project that I am working on is a video game, and in that video game there are missions for the player(s) to complete. Well, some of these missions give the player reward items upon completion and some do not.  I have one SQL table that holds all of the missions' info and another that holds the rewards that those missions give.  If the missions' rewards table does not contain rewards for a given mission, then that missions does give rewards upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to skip when it occurs.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

use continue;

```
if (empty(resultsRow [3])){
  continue;   // will check new row
}
else {
rightColumn1 = resultsRow [3];
rightColumn2 = resultsRow [4];
rightColumn3 = resultsRow [5];
}
```

I wish this is what you were looking for !

I have studied C++ but php is very amazing as it's much easier !
Enjoy your Coding !

PS: I don't know your query is alright or not but if you describe what you want, I can check it. Simply add, table and result you expect

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply and thanks for your reply Jenam.  I see what your technique is, and it is valid, or rather, would be if my problem were that resultsRow[3] is simply empty (or, undefined), but it is not; my problem is that trying to do anything with resultsRow[3] causes an error, because it is not even part of the array (which stops at index [2]).  Unless I am mistaken, the "emtpy()" function that you included in your example is a a function that I have to implement, not a built-in function?  Let me know if I am misunderstanding what you are telling me. Thanks again.